# Wrong values for self.view.frame even after adding Launch Images and a Launch Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have been frustratingly stuck on this issue for the last 2 days. I have gone through and followed most of the StackOverflow questions regarding adding Launch Images and/or a Launch Screen so that the app isn't zoomed on iPhone 6/6s and iPhone 6 plus sizes.

I have made sure to add the Launch Images with correct dimensions, 750x1334 and 1242x2208.

Even after doing this and adding a Launch Screen, when I print `self.view.frame.size.height` and `self.view.frame.size.width`, it is always 568 and 320 respectively.

Can someone please help me with this. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
The first screen that is shown used to be a subclass of another `UIViewController` called `BaseViewController` but not I changed it and made the first screen a subview of `UIViewController`.

I am not sure if I have missed some important step in allowing the app to function on bigger screen sizes.

Any help would be great!

I look forward to your responses. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What dimensions you are expecting when print the frame ?

Comment: I am currently testing on iPhone 6 and 6s, both of which should be width: 375 and height: 667, right?

Comment: @Aashay Where did you print your values. If you initiate your view controller via xib or storyboard with auto layout and print your values in viewDidLoad, the moment can't guarantee get correct values since the view is still populating.

Comment: Where did you print the frame ? and How can you assure that you are running it on iphone 6 ?

Comment: @Allen Yes, all the view setup is done from viewDidLoad. Should I move everything to viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: never check the view frames or any UI related stuff in view did load.@Aashay

Comment: So should I move everything from viewDidLoad to another method? If so, what method would you recommend I move it to? @Mr.T

Comment: is it the only frame values that are wrong or is there any issue related to ui ?@Aashay

Comment: viewWillAppear will be sufficient enough!!! If it didnt workout, try in viewDIdappear

Comment: @Aashay Don't move everything. Only just your print out. viewDidAppear is a better place to check frame values.

Comment: @Mr.T All the views in my app seem to have the width 320 and height 568

Comment: Are you using storybaord/ autolayout ?

Comment: I'm using .xibs and autolayout @Mr.T

Comment: You should be logging [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size instead of view size.

Comment: I can use [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size but my question is, why are all my views in the entire not able to fit correctly according to the size of the screen? @Xcoder

Comment: @Aashay I think I missed a possibility. If you set other UI components based on self.view.frame in viewDidLoad, that would not be a good idea either.

Comment: @Allen I am moving everything to viewDidAppear. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Allen I had one more question, I am checking the Preview of each of my .xib on all the 4 screen sizes. It shows the layout correctly but when I run it on my device, none of the constraints seem to be upheld. Any idea why this might be happening?